# Compare two Text Files, Output in Third File

Tags: python

[File 1.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5jeh.png)

[File 2.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVbfd.png)

[Output File Reference Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2Rs6.png)

I tried but i got the out put in another way

```
`import re, glob, logging
```

from itertools import izip

def FindDiff (Doc1, Doc2, Doc3):

```
doc1read = open (Doc1,'r')
doc2read = open (Doc2,'r')
doc3write = open (Doc3,'w+')
find_pattern = r'\b\d*\.\d+|\d+\b'
lineno = 1
lines1 = doc1read.readline()
lines2 = doc2read.readline()
while lines1:
    regex1 = re.findall(find_pattern, lines1)
    regex2 = re.findall(find_pattern, lines2)
    length = len(regex1)-1
    for x in range (0, length):
        if (regex1[x] != regex2[x]):
            doc3write.write("File 1 has "+lines1+"and File 2 has "+lines2+"at line -" + str(lineno) + "\n")

            print regex1
            print regex2
            break
    lineno = lineno+1
    lines1 = doc1read.readline()
    lines2 = doc2read.readline()
doc1read.close()
doc2read.close()
doc3write.close()
```

FindDiff('D:/F1.txt', 'D:/F2.txt','D:/F3.txt')`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, please, format your code correctly, don't add irrelevant tags (java), don't paste links to external images containing screenshots of text.

Comment: why did you tag this java

Comment: Please edit your post, select the code, and click the `{}` widget to render it as code.  That widget will shift it right 4 spaces in the edit window; look at the preview below to make sure your indentation looks right.

Comment: Also, you need to tell us what was wrong with your output.  Just saying "another way" isn't much help.  To get help from us, you must help us help  you.  Do all the work you can think of doing to make it easy for others to help you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you must use python, but you can do it as follows at the command as follows:

```
$diff --suppress-common-lines dif1.txt dif2.txt |grep -e '[><]'|cut -c2-
```

to save the output you can do as follows:

```
$diff --suppress-common-lines D:/F1.txt D:/F2.txt |grep -e '[><]'|cut -c2- > D:/F3.txt
```